# WPF: Combobox in TreeviewItem

Tags: wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I'm newbie in WPF, so sorry about stupid question.

It is possible to show combobox side by side with selected TreeViewItem?

I need something like shown in the left picture at the following link: http://www.mypicx.com/03242009/Combobox_in_TreeviewItem/

I tried to do thus:

`<TreeView Name="treeView1">

            <TreeViewItem Header="aaa">

                <ComboBox Height="19">

                    <ComboBoxItem Content="111" IsSelected="True"></ComboBoxItem>

                    <ComboBoxItem>222</ComboBoxItem>

                    <ComboBoxItem Content="333"></ComboBoxItem>

                </ComboBox>

                <TreeViewItem Header="aaa1">

                </TreeViewItem>

                <TreeViewItem Header="aaa2">

                </TreeViewItem>

            </TreeViewItem>

            <TreeViewItem Header="bbb">

                <TreeViewItem Header="bbb1" />

                <TreeViewItem Header="bbb2" />

            </TreeViewItem>

            <TreeViewItem Header="ccc" />

        </TreeView>`

and the result you can see in the right picture.

Meantime I need to know, how to do this visually. Later I need to do something with SelectedItemChanged event.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. sorry about my english

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is put your combo box inside your Header like such

```
<TreeView Name="treeView1">
    <TreeViewItem>
        <TreViewItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox Height="19">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="111" IsSelected="True"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>222</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="333"></ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </TreViewItem.Header>
        <TreeViewItem Header="aaa1">
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="aaa2">
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem Header="bbb">
        <TreeViewItem Header="bbb1" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="bbb2" />
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem Header="ccc" />
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an ItemTemplate.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ec6781bb-a81d-4204-bc13-937683110b0d/